# In set theory, what do the subscripts $A_1,A_2,\dotsc,A_n$ mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

How are subscripts used in set theory, for example, In set theory, what do the subscripts $A_1,A_2,\dotsc,A_n$ mean?

Comment: They should be defined to have meaning.

Comment: Usually, each one is a different set.

Comment: It depends on context.  They might be subsets of some previously-mentioned $A$, they might be some finite family of otherwise unrelated sets.  The thing you're reading should say what they are. Without more information, nobody will be able to answer your question.

Comment: You can usually treat each $A_i$ as a separate variable - as if they'd written $A,B,C,\ldots,Z$ instead (but they wouldn't have a way to index them in that case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just means that $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ are sets. It is *often* the case that they are distinct, but if it was not mentioned then it might be the case that $A_1=A_2=\ldots=A_n$.

The subscript is just an index. And formally it means that there is a function $A$ whose domain is $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and we write $A_i$ for the set obtained by $A(i)$. Any additional assumptions need to be mentioned explicitly.

We may assume, of course, that there is some set $X$ such that $A_i\subseteq X$, simply by taking $X=\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$. But this is really not different from having $n_1,\ldots,n_k$ some natural numbers or $r_1,\ldots,r_k$ some real numbers.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand.  Just to clarify, would $A_1,A_2,\dotsc,A_n$ be sets based on a larger set A?  Otherwise, I guess I am confused on why not just call each of those sets, A, B, C instead?

Comment: Because something you want $n$ to be very large, or arbitrary, and there are only so many letters in the English alphabet.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm wondering why we need to write that k=1. Couldn't it be equal to zero or even a negative number? I mean it's just naming after all.

Comment: @Manar: It's just an index. It doesn't matter. And since it doesn't, you might as well do it in a way that makes sense to the context. In most cases, it means starting from $1$ or $0$, but in others it might also mean using negative or real numbers, or anything, really.